# Mocha: Timeout on endpoint that is functional

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai, supertest

When using Mocha, supertest, and Chai, when I run the code:

```
const authPost = (title, endpoint, body, responseProperty, checkFirstElement = false) => {
    it(title, (done) => {
        request(app)
            .post(endpoint)
            .set({ "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}` })
            .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .send(body)
            .end((error, response) => {
                if (error) done(error);
                checkFirstElement ? response.body[0].should.have.property(responseProperty) : response.body.should.have.property(responseProperty);
                done();
            });
    });
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/drone/src/test/test.js)
          at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
          at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

I initially thought it was a timeout error, but I have had it run for a long time and I cannot solve the issue.

Things I've tried:

- Verified that the endpoint is actually accessible
- Removing the Content-Type set statement
- Adding a .catch(done) after the request
- calling it() directly where the error was happening as opposed to calling the function and adding the JSON data directly into the function as well

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you please share more code on how you are using this part in tests?

Comment: @pauleg To be honest, there isn't much else. The only other things that occur are the initialization of the database and the setting of the token which is successfully received from the API using this function but without the two set methods.

To add, there are similar calls that occur before this one that are successful.

I can post the API functionality, but in will always respond with an error if the payload is incorrect. I just cannot figure out if there is an error in my syntax or if there is something that I am potentially missing.

Comment: At first, try to make your tests more isolated and static, it's a good practice to split tests into test cases based on positive/negative scenarios. your tests should not contain a lot of logic and should be quite KISS

Comment: next - try to refactor to use async/await syntax which will give you a more comfortable appearance. looks like its just a wrongly used callback function, so done is not called in the right way alongside with test's callback

Comment: Thanks for the information, @pauleg! I really appreciate it. I'll attempt to do that.